# Integration of hibernate transaction in jta transaction manager

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, jta, transactionmanager

In my standalone java application, jms and hibernate are used for fulfilling my requirements. I used the JTA transaction manager for the transaction management purposes. Can i enlist the XAResource for the hibernate and jms in the jta transaction to ensure the atomicity of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Called sometimes two-phase commit, it synchronises transactions between multiple resources.

First of all make sure you're RDBMS supports and has the feature turned on. In PostgreSQL, for example, this means setting the `max_prepared_transactions` configuration parameter from `postgresql.conf` to something above `0`.

Also, make sure the JMS queue you're using support this transaction method. In Wildfly this means adding `transaction="xa"` on `pooled-connection-factory`.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail for the point - how we get the XAResource for the hibernate transactions. I implemented the jta transaction manager and trying to enlist the XAResource from the hibernate. please explain with example.

Comment: What tech are you using (database, application server, etc)?

Comment: i implemented jta transaction manager support in my core java application. oracle is used as my data base. Now i am planing to use hibernate for interacting with the data base. how can i include the hibernate transaction in the scope of my jta transaction ? Please help